# How can I search any item in the below json data

Tags: javascript, json

How can I search any item from the json data using a single forin loop.
I had tried searching one but what if I wanted to search from any other field.
For instance if I  wanted to search whether an item from featuredBrands exist or not and if exist return the item.

```js
var users = [{
    "userProfile": {
      "firstName": "Rahul",
      "lastName": "Jhawar",
      "cartitemsno": 2,
      "items": ["THINK AND GROW RICH", "Lenovo Z2 Plus"]
    }
  },

  {
    "dayDeals": [{
        "productCategory": "Sports & Fitness Gear",
        "discount": "20-80% off",
        "items": "Yonex,Li-Ning & more"
      },
      {
        "productCategory": "Best Ethnic Trends",
        "discount": "50-80% off",
        "items": "Kurtas,Sarees & more"
      },
      {
        "productCategory": "Popular Brands",
        "discount": "60-80% off",
        "items": "T-shirts,Shirts,Jeans"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featuredBrands": [{
        "brandName": "Ambrane",
        "userRating": 3.7
      },
      {

        "brandName": "Sony",
        "userRating": 4.2

      },
      {
        "brandName": "IPro",
        "userRating": 4.0
      }
    ]
  },
  {

    "recommendedItems": [{
        "itemName": "Stay Hungry Stay Foolish",
        "productCategory": "Books",
        "prouctPrice": "Rs 186",
        "offer": "3%"
      },
      {
        "itemName": "iPro IP 43 20800 mAh Power Bank  (White & Grey, Lithium-ion)",
        "productCategory": "Mobile Accessories",
        "prouctPrice": "Rs 1199",
        "offer": "60%"
      },
      {
        "itemName": "Micromax Canvas Pulse 4G (Grey, 16 GB)  (3 GB RAM)",
        "productCategory": "Mobile Phones",
        "prouctPrice": "Rs 11199",
        "offer": "12%"
      }
    ]

  }
]

var displayitem = function(users, name) {

  for (var item in users) {

    if (users[item].userProfile.firstName == name) {
      return users[item].userProfile.firstName;
    } else {
      return "Item not found"
    }
  }
};

console.log(displayitem(users, "Rahul"));
```

Comment: Why are you trying to only use a single for loop? It's not considered "wrong" to nest multiple loops within one another. Also, your code will vary depending upon what you're looking to search for...

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the array

See my second example. Your JSON is not logical. The 0th item is the userPRofile, then the 1st item is dayDeals and the 2nd the featured brands. The 3rd item in the array is the recommendedItems but they are not related to the user

```js
var displayitem = function(users, name) {

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var userProfile = users[i].userProfile;
    if (userProfile.firstName == name) {
      return userProfile.items;
    }
  }
  return "Item not found"
};

var displayitem1 = function(users, name) {
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var recommendedItems = users[i].recommendedItems;
    if (recommendedItems) {
      for (var j = 0; j < recommendedItems.length; j++) {
        if (recommendedItems[j].itemName == name) {
          return i+"."+j+" name:"+name+" found";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
};


var users = [{
    "userProfile": {
      "firstName": "Rahul",
      "lastName": "Jhawar",
      "cartitemsno": 2,
      "items": ["THINK AND GROW RICH", "Lenovo Z2 Plus"]
    }
  },

  {
    "dayDeals": [{
        "productCategory": "Sports & Fitness Gear",
        "discount": "20-80% off",
        "items": "Yonex,Li-Ning & more"
      },
      {
        "productCategory": "Best Ethnic Trends",
        "discount": "50-80% off",
        "items": "Kurtas,Sarees & more"
      },
      {
        "productCategory": "Popular Brands",
        "discount": "60-80% off",
        "items": "T-shirts,Shirts,Jeans"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "featuredBrands": [{
        "brandName": "Ambrane",
        "userRating": 3.7
      },
      {

        "brandName": "Sony",
        "userRating": 4.2

      },
      {
        "brandName": "IPro",
        "userRating": 4.0
      }
    ]
  },
  {

    "recommendedItems": [{
        "itemName": "Stay Hungry Stay Foolish",
        "productCategory": "Books",
        "prouctPrice": "Rs 186",
        "offer": "3%"
      },
      {
        "itemName": "iPro IP 43 20800 mAh Power Bank  (White & Grey, Lithium-ion)",
        "productCategory": "Mobile Accessories",
        "prouctPrice": "Rs 1199",
        "offer": "60%"
      },
      {
        "itemName": "Micromax Canvas Pulse 4G (Grey, 16 GB)  (3 GB RAM)",
        "productCategory": "Mobile Phones",
        "prouctPrice": "Rs 11199",
        "offer": "12%"
      }
    ]

  }
]

//console.log(displayitem(users, "Rahul"));
console.log(displayitem1(users, "Stay Hungry Stay Foolish"));
```

Comment: var displayitem = function(users, name) {

  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var recommendedItems = users[i].recommendedItems;
    if (recommendedItems.itemName == name) {
      return recommendedItems.itemName;
    } else {
      return "Item not found"
    }
  }
};

console.log(displayitem(users, "Stay Hungry Stay Foolish"));